# Is it possible to make a cycle swipe items in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I use swipeview in qml. I can swipe items from first to final and back. Is it possible to swipe from final to first immediatly ? I didn't find any information in docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [`PathView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html). Qt Quick Controls 2's [`Tumbler`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html) can also be made to [`wrap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html#wrap-prop) because it uses `PathView` internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PathView, like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ListModel {
        id: model
        ListElement { color: "red"   }
        ListElement { color: "green" }
        ListElement { color: "blue"  }
    }

    Component {
        id: delegate
        Rectangle {
            id: wrapper
            width: view.width
            height: view.height
            color: model.color

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.pointSize: 26
                font.bold: true
                color: "white"
                text: index
            }
        }
    }

    PathView {
        id: view

        anchors.fill: parent

        snapMode: PathView.SnapOneItem
        highlightRangeMode: PathView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        currentIndex: -1

        model: model
        delegate: delegate

        path: Path {
            startX: -view.width / 2  // let the first item in left
            startY: view.height / 2  // item's vertical center is the same as line's

            PathLine {
                relativeX: view.width * view.model.count  // all items in lines
                relativeY: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```