# How to create Bidirectional SwipeView?

Tags: qt, qml

In QML How Can I create circular SwipeView? 
Means If I am at last element, them next Item should be the first One.

SwipeView {
        id: view
        spacing: 20
        currentIndex: 0
        clip: true
        anchors.fill: parent
       }

Or Can I use tumbler which can contain different Items?

I am using this code

```
    PathView {
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent
    snapMode:PathView.NoSnap
    property int widthAllList: (widthItemNotSelect*3)+60
    property int widthItemNotSelect: parent.width-13
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
    preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5
    model: ["qrc:/QML/Widget/AnalogClock.qml",
        "qrc:/QML/Widget/Clock.qml"
        ,"qrc:/QML/Widget/Widget.qml"]
    delegate: Loader {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        source: modelData
    }
    path: Path {
        id:myPath
        startX: 0
        startY: parent.height/2
        PathLine { x:view.widthAllList; y:parent.height/2 }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I guess you have to try `PathView` instead.

Comment: Actually I have different QML to be shown. In Path View similer data can be shown as Delegate will be same.

Comment: You can use a [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) in your PathView delegate to load different components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a cycle swipe items in qml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847767/is-it-possible-to-make-a-cycle-swipe-items-in-qml)

Comment: Thanks folibis,
Please have a look in my code, Which I updated in my question itself.
when I start dragging then the loaded Qml gets unloaded in the moving tile,(which is not required).

Comment: You should not change source, people will be confusing while searching for similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The simple example using [PathView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html):

```
PathView {
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent
    snapMode: PathView.SnapToItem
    model: ["Test1.qml","Test2.qml","Test3.qml"]
    delegate: Loader {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        source: modelData           
    }
    path: Path {
        startX: view.width/2; startY: view.height/2
        PathQuad { x: view.width/2; y: -view.height*view.model.length; controlX: -view.width; controlY: view.height/2 }
        PathQuad { x: view.width/2; y: view.height/2; controlX: view.width * view.model.length; controlY: view.height/2 }
    }
}
```

The path in example above is for fun and example only, you can modify it as you want.

Example of item - **Test1.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Rectangle{
    color: "green"
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "page " + index
    }
}
```

The same trick could be done using `Tumbler`, I guess.

Comment: Thank for answering,
I used this approach , in this approach when I start dragging then the loaded Qml gets unloaded in the moving tile,(which is not required).
It happens because index is changing, and after half way it starts unloading the QML, & loads new qml.

Comment: set [Loader.active](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#active-prop) to true

Comment: Loader.active is by default true.
Do i need to make any change in PathLine also? In my example I have only 1 instance of PathLine, & in your example you have 2 instances of PathQuad.

Comment: Yes, you're right, so there is no reason that `Loader` will unload its items until you didn't force it. How do you know it was unloaded?

Comment: Actually I have a View let's say Rectangle. So this path view view has anchors.fill : rectangle, OK ,  Now if I add 3 items in Path view & make it in a PathLine So while moving center item to left, the left Item pops out & joins the last one , & vice versa.

So here I want untill i reach the left corner of parent Rectangle left item should not pop out.